# Why the elements shifted when I try add them on the page by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I try to add html code on page by using jquery function .after(), but added elements look not like elements added by pure html. Why it so happen and how to solve this problem?
The gaps between "Text" and input are not equal after inserting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").on('click', function() {
      var html =  ""
      + "<div>"
        + "<span>Text:</span>" 
        + "<input type='text' />"
      + "</div>";   
      $('#xxx').after(html);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div style="width: 350px">
  <div id='xxx'>
    <span>Text:</span>
    <input type='text' />
  </div>
</div>

<input id='b' type="button" value="Insert">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the whitespace between the `span` and the `input`. If you want the gap to remain, add a space between them in your JS string:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").on('click', function() {
      var html = "<div>"
        + "<span>Text:</span> " // add space at the end here
        + "<input type='text' />"
        + "</div>";   
      $('#xxx').after(html);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 350px">
  <div id='xxx'>
    <span>Text:</span>
    <input type='text' />
  </div>
</div>
<input id='b' type="button" value="Insert">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in your existing `html`

Check your updated code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").on('click', function() {
      var html =  ""
      + "<div>"
        + "<span>Text:</span>" 
        + "<input type='text' />"
      + "</div>";   
      $('#xxx').after(html);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div style="width: 350px">
  <div id='xxx'>
    <span>Text:</span><input type='text' />
  </div>
</div>

<input id='b' type="button" value="Insert">
```